# Linux Software RAID: How to fsck on hard drive?

Tags: linux, raid, hard-drive, software-raid, fsck

We have a Linux server running with Software RAID1. We see some issues in `/var/log/messages` like: *unreadable sector*. I want to perform a complete `fsck` on the drive to get some more information, but a `fsck /dev/md0` brings a clean due to the Software RAID layer in between. How can I check the real hard drive? Do I need to disassemble the whole RAID? How do I deal with the inconsistency in the partition due to the additional Software RAID header?

Does anyone have a good idea for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fsck` tests the filesystem, but this should be fine as long as the RAID hasn't failed completely.

To test the disk itself, use `badblocks` (in package `e2fsprogs`).

```
badblocks /dev/sda
```

Comment: It's ok to use `badblocks` without `-n` or `-w` on online filesystem, since it doesnt' do any writing. Changing any data on disk doesn't affect badblocks behaviour.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I misinterpreted the `-n` option.

Comment: Recommend use arg `-s` to show progress